# Where is WindowsError defined?

Tags: python

I am beginner. Here to learn.

A piece of code is throwing a WindowsError. I catch it and rename it to `exception`.

I introspect the object, through `dir(exception)`, `type(exception)`, `print(exception.__dict__)` trying to find a reference to run some documentation command on: e.g. help(areference)`.

I can't find where WindowsError was defined. I tried `help(os.WindowsError)` but that obviously lead to nowhere.

The ultimate intent is to locate where WindowsError comes from but for this question, as I got the answer from Google somehow, I would like to **learn** how to find this out through Python commands.

Specifically:

- Get the module in which a type is defined
- Get the supertype of a class I get in an exception (or even... *any class*?!)

Am I introspecting wrong? Are there better ways to do that?

Comment: Is it possible to always get the supertype of a class?  Python *does* support multiple inheritance.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Yes it is always possible.

Comment: @DavidHefferman I guess I was just contemplating the paradigm of walking an inheritance chain with multiple inheritance at play.  The answer(ers?) seem to have mentioned that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to give a look at the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module. In particular the [`inspect.getmodule`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule) function.

To obtain the parent classes of a class you can simply look at a class `__bases__` attribute:

```
>>> IOError.__bases__
(<type 'exceptions.EnvironmentError'>,)
```

Or you can obtain the hierarchy of classes through the `__mro__` attribute:

```
>>> IOError.__mro__
(<type 'exceptions.IOError'>, <type 'exceptions.EnvironmentError'>, <type 'exceptions.StandardError'>, <type 'exceptions.Exception'>, <type 'exceptions.BaseException'>, <type 'object'>)
```

The `__mro__` tells you in which order python looks methods and attributes in the class hierarchy.

Note that, since python allows multiple inheritance, you cannot define the concept of "super-class". Each class can have more than one parent class, and the hierarchy can become a quite complicated graph, and trying to think of super-classes will only lead to pitfalls(e.g. calls to methods fails when the subclasses redefine the signature etc. etc.)

Comment: AttributeError: 'WindowsError' object has no attribute '__bases__'. Same thing for mro. Why is that? :(

Comment: @Robottinosino You asked about types not instances. The `WindowsError` type has the attribute `__bases__`.

Comment: I see! So I need first to type(instance) and then to `inspect` on the reference I get... gotcha, I think! ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1: Module in which a type is defined**

According to my Python, it's defined in the built in module named `exceptions`:

```
>>> WindowsError
<type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>
```

Programmatically you can find out the module in which a type is defined by reading its `__module__` attribute:

```
>>> WindowsError.__module__
'exceptions'
>>> sys.modules[WindowsError.__module__]
<module 'exceptions' (built-in)>
```

**Question 2: Find the superclasses of a type**

The `__bases__` attribute of a type list its superclasses.

```
>>> WindowsError.__bases__
(<type 'exceptions.OSError'>,)
```

**Question 3: What is the type of a given object**

You didn't actually ask this question, but your comments indicate that you should have done so. To find the type of an object use the `type()` function.

```
>>> i = 666
>>> type(i)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(i).__bases__
(<type 'object'>,)
>>> type(i).__module__
'__builtin__'
```

So, when you catch an exception, you have an object rather than a type, that is you have an instance of the class. So to learn about the type you must first use `type()` to obtain the type.

Comment: How would you do that programmatically? i.e. from a type name, get a odule name..

Comment: @Robottinosino Given a type name you **can't** determine which module defines it in any smart way if it is not a built-in(which can be `eval`ed). Python is not java that enforces a really strong relationship between module names and classes, so the only feasible approach is to import any possible module and check.

Comment: Really? :( Import every possible module?

Comment: BTW, the WindowsError I catch has no __module__ attribute?

Comment: You don't catch a class. You catch an instance. What is it that you actually want? The question asks about types. Now in comments you ask about names. And then move on to instances. It's not much fun answering a question and then having the question change. I believe I have answered both of the questions that you asked.

Comment: David, I just did not understand enough to even be posing the question when I did. That's all. I did mention I am a beginner.. I am only high-school educated..

Comment: No probs. I don't think you need inspect for what you are asking. You can do `type(obj).__module__` and it's all good.